Side notes but not in the margin
Sometimes, I find inserting notes like the blue text in the below image useful. It may not be as simple as the one in the example (possibilities include inserting an image, or maybe even a tikz code). But I do not want to switch to, say, tufte-latex, just because of that. What choices do I have?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
Substitute $u=z^2+1$
\begin{align*}
    \displaystyle\int\frac{2z}{\sqrt[3]{z^2+1}}\,dz &=\int\displaystyle\frac{u}{u^{1/3}}\,du\\
    &=\displaystyle\int u^{-1/3}\,du\\
    &=\frac{3}{2}(z^2+1)^{2/3}+C
\end{align*}
\end{document}



Can you please add code? Thank you

In the case as shown in the picture, just use alignat from amsmath package. If you want to insert a picture, it's a good idea to use minipage.

unrelated but your \displaystyle are doing nothing (``align*` isalready a display environment)

Take a look at the witharrows package : https://ctan.org/pkg/witharrows .

Use a further alignment point.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{stepnote}{blue!70}
\newcommand{\stepnote}[1]{&&\text{\color{stepnote}#1}}

\begin{document}

Substitute $u=z^2+1$
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{2z}{\sqrt[3]{z^2+1}}\,dz
  &=\int\frac{1}{u^{1/3}}\,du \stepnote{First step} \\
  &=\int u^{-1/3}\,du \stepnote{Second step} \\
  &=\frac{3}{2}(z^2+1)^{2/3}+C \stepnote{Final step}
\end{align*}

\end{document}


I removed all the \displaystyle declarations that are already implicit in align. And also fixed a small math mistake.
If you want to reduce the amount of space, use alignat with a small change in \stepnote:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{stepnote}{blue!70}
\newcommand{\stepnote}[1]{&\qquad&\text{\color{stepnote}#1}}

\begin{document}

Substitute $u=z^2+1$
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\int\frac{2z}{\sqrt[3]{z^2+1}}\,dz
  &=\int\frac{1}{u^{1/3}}\,du \stepnote{First step} \\
  &=\int u^{-1/3}\,du \stepnote{Second step} \\
  &=\frac{3}{2}(z^2+1)^{2/3}+C \stepnote{Final step}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}



In OpTeX, we can do something very similar like in egreg's answer:
\def\stepnote#1{&&&\hbox{\Cyan#1}}

Substitute $u=z^2+1$
$$
\eqalign{
\int {2z\over \root3\of{z^2+1}}\,dz
  &=\int {1\over u^{1/3}}\,du          \stepnote{First step} \cr
  &=\int u^{-1/3}\,du                  \stepnote{Second step} \cr
  &={3\over 2}(z^2+1)^{2/3}+C          \stepnote{Final step}
}
$$

\bye

